# Show selected combobox item display name

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a ComboBox with `ValueMember="Id"` and `DisplayMember="Id"` and want to display selected item property `Name` in label, after some value in `ComboBox` in selected. I'm using some sort of `MVVM pattern`. So, I'm binding `SelectedId` to **Model** and `ItemsSource` to **ViewModel**. 
(If I put `ItemsSource` in **Model** it is easy - using setters and `OnPropertyChanged()`, but now I have in model a lot of fields which are used only for UI representation)

I've managed to shown selected item's Name using combobox `LostFocus` event, where I call `ViewModel` method in which I get property `Name` using LINQ (from List, 
where `l.Id=Model.SelectedId`).

But, is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 1):

You *could* bind directly to the combobox for your label:

```
     <ComboBox Name="MyCombo" ItemsSource="{Binding ComboListObjects}" SelectedItem="{Binding ComboSelection}" />
        <Label Content="{Binding ElementName=MyCombo, Path=SelectedValue}"/>
```

However, since you are using a ViewModel, you should probably change things around a bit.  There is no SelectedId on Combobox, so I assume you mean SelectedValue.  Instead, I suggest creating a property on your ViewModel to hold the SelectedItem.  I have included a sample:

ViewModel:

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   public List<MyObject> ComboListObjects
    { 
        get{
            return new List<MyObject>();  // <-- fill this
        }
    }

    private MyObject _selectedItem = null;
    public MyObject ComboSelection
    {
        get { return _selectedItem; }
        set {
            _selectedItem = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("ComboSelection");
        }
    }
}
```

View:

```
    <ComboBox Name="MyCombo" ItemsSource="{Binding ComboListObjects}" SelectedItem="{Binding ComboSelection}" />
    <Label Content="{Binding ComboSelection.Id}"/>
    <Label Content="{Binding ComboSelection.Name}"/>
    <Label Content="{Binding ComboSelection.OtherInfo}"/>
```

If you are going to be using MVVM, avoid using the codebehind, especially events, unless you are writing a custom control.

Hope that helps...

Comment: I agree. `SelectedItem` is the way to go because then he can bind any other field to the SelectedItem (or a property on that SelectedItem).

Comment: thanks. But now the problem is that I use entlib validator in Model, and if I bind selected ComboBox object to ViewModel then I can't show validation result image in ComboBox (because Combobox is binding ViewModel.Object, not the Model.SelectedObjectId)

Comment: that, my friend, is a horse of a different color.  You should check or change the validator accordingly (so it doesn't require the ID, but can resolve the ID from the instance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to bind a combo box to a list of books and display the title of the book on a label using MVVM.

In xaml markup, bind the combobox to your view model using the ItemsSource and SelectedItem properties

```
<ComboBox Name="cbBook" ItemsSource="{Binding Books}"  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedBook, Mode=TwoWay}" />
<Label DataContext="{Binding SelectedBook}" Content="{Binding Title}" />
```

In your view, set the DataContext to your view model class

```
public partial class MyView : UserControl
{
    public MyView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new BookViewModel();
    }
}
```

The view model should have public properties you'll be binding to.

```
public class BookViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public BookViewModel()
    {
       Books = new ObservableCollection<Book>();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Book> Books { get; set; }

    private Book _selectedBook; 
    public Book SelectedBook 
    { 
       get { return _selectedBook; } 
       set
       {
          _selectedBook = value;
          NotifyPropertyChanged(() => SelectedBook); 
       }
    }
}
```

This base class implements the INotifyPropertyChanged interface. I'm using a lambda expression for type safety.

```
public abstract class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged<T>(Expression<Func<T>> expression)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(((MemberExpression)expression.Body).Member.Name));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```